# AngularFire: how to set only a property?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Just beginning with firebase... :-(

How do I set a property of an item?
This is my data structure:

```
myproject
|
- players
  |
  - -JPUAYuKUNeevXxaCMxM
    |
    - name: "John"
    |
    - skill
      |
      - mu: 25
      |
      - sigma: 8.333

  - -JPUAYuRyJBH8sF93pNt
    ...
```

I can add a player with:

```
 var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/' + 'players');
 ref.child(id).set(player);
```

The question is: how do I update only one property of an item (for example, 'skill') ?
I did try with:

```
var skill = {};
skill.mu = 27.0;
skill.sigma = 7.0;
ref.child(id).skill.update(skill);
```

Comment: What happened and what were you expecting?

Comment: This is the error: "Error: ref.child(...).skill is undefined". I would expect no error, and firebase to be updated with new skill...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what's going on here.

You expected `ref.child(id)` to have a property `skill`. However, you actually want the "skill" child; `ref.child(id).child("skill")`.

Comment: Yes, thanks... I could solve with: `ref.child(id).child('skill').set(skill);`